# CRUD error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

Hello guys I made a CRUD(just create and read ) in Laravel project ,the create is working good and i passed the "loan" in show function but in the view it says undefined variable:

my show function in controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $loan=loan::find($id);

        return view('finance/loans')->with('loan',$loan); 
    }
```

My routes:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/loans', 'LoanController@viewLoanForm');
Route::post('/loans', 'LoanController@store');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('loan','loanController');
Route::get('finance/loans', function () {
    return view('loans');
});
```

And here is where i call the variable loan in the view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<link href="{{ asset('css/loans.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">


<html>

        <div class="container">
...

                </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                <h1>{{$loan->nume}}</h1>//"nume"is the row from db i want to show

                </div>


            </div>

    </html>
    @endsection
```

[The ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPNRw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to on the route::resource('finance/loans') instead of ('loans').
And will work for sure

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled the route!
Your request does not reach the controller method

```
Route::get('finance/loans', function () {
    return view('loans');
 });
```

should be so

```
Route::get('finance/loans/{$id}','loanController@show');
```

or should use the controller resource route

```
Route::resource('loans','loanController');
```

url 'loans/show/{$loan_id}'

`<a  href="route('loans.show',[$id])">Show Loan</a>`

Comment: in your file of routes you wrote Route::resource('loans','loanController')?  
you have written Route::resource('loan','loanController')

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers  in resource controllers url must be in the plural, and the model in the singular.

Answer (score 1):

your return should be like this:

```
return view('finance/loans')->with(['loan'=>$loan]);
```

instead of

```
return view('finance/loans')->with('loan',$loan);
```

Comment: still same  problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
return view('finance.loans',compact(['loan']));
```

Comment: Is your loans.blade.php file in finance folder?

Comment: For what purpose you are using this:? Route::get('finance/loans', function () {
    return view('loans');
});

Comment: i am using it becouse is the route for my view "loans" where i want to make the crud.Here i have a button that adds to db dates(create) and it works so i think all the routes are good.

Comment: it is screenshooted in the question .Press on"THE ERROR" at the final of the question.

Comment: Put this blade file into finance folder

Comment: You are getting this error becaue loans file is calling from Route::get('finance/loans', function () { return view('loans'); });  and here you are not passing loan variable